# How can I create random objects from a bunch of classes (herited classes)

Tags: c#, random, binary-search-tree

I'm sorry if there is a similar question, tried searching but didn't find an adequate response for my use.

I have 5 classes that herits from one class (spaceshipclass) and I need to create random objects from each class and store them in a binary tree.
with each one of the objects, two random integers as shown in the code bellow.

```
public class spaceships
{
    int cost;
    int combatPower;
    private Random rand = new Random();

     public spaceships(int cost, int combatPower)
    {
        this.cost = cost;
        this.combatPower = combatPower;

        cost = rand.Next(10000, 1000000);
        combatPower = rand.Next(20, 100);

    }

} 

public class Patrol : spaceships
{
        public Patrol (int cost,int combatPower) : base(cost,combatPower)
        {
        }
}
```

the second class is one of the inherited classes.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: `cost = rand.Next(10000, 1000000)` will assign  a random number to the method parameter `cost` which is not further used.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a disconnect between the desired functionality and the posted code, as your `spaceships` class takes in a `cost` and `combatPower` in its constructor, but then ignores that and calculates those values itself. Because of this, I'm going to ignore that particular implementation and just go ahead and calculate those values before constructing the random objects, as your question title requests. Keep in mind that my solution allows you to remove the private `Random rand` field of your spaceships class entirely.

You could use a simple `switch` statement to determine which type of spaceships to create, and then add them to your collection (you mention a binary search tree but that's an implementation detail that doesn't really matter here, so long as it is of type `spaceships` to support the polymorphism your question mentions).

```
Random rand = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < numSpaceshipsRequired; i++)
{
    int typeOfSpaceship = rand.Next(0, 5);
    int cost = rand.Next(10000, 1000000);
    int combatPower = rand.Next(20, 100);
    
    switch (typeOfSpaceship)
    {
        case 0:
            collection.Add(new Patrol(cost, combatPower));
            break;
        case 1:
            collection.Add(new Cruiser(cost, combatPower));
            break;
        case 2:
            collection.Add(new Frigate(cost, combatPower));
            break;
        case 3:
            collection.Add(new Fighter(cost, combatPower));
            break;
        case 4:
            collection.Add(new Stealth(cost, combatPower));
            break;
    }
}
```